# how can undo sequelize migration enum type

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I use PostgreSQL DB and it has an enum type column and it has some enum like **a,b,c**

now I add one more value like **cv-resume** in it with this code

```js
module.exports = {
up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      await queryInterface.sequelize.query('ALTER TYPE "enum_Attachment_type" ADD VALUE \'cv-resume\' ')
}
```

what I should do to undo that in down function and I don't want to delete other enum type data
because each type has its own data in Attachment table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html):

> Although enum types are primarily intended for static sets of values,
> there is support for adding new values to an existing enum type, and
> for renaming values (see ALTER TYPE). Existing values cannot be
> removed from an enum type, nor can the sort ordering of such values be
> changed, short of dropping and re-creating the enum type.

So I don't see any other way to "undo" other than dropping and recreating the enum.

UPDATE: check [Drop and create ENUM with sequelize correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437924/drop-and-create-enum-with-sequelize-correctly)