# Sequelize removeColumn method doesn't remove enum types

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, migration

I added a column to an already existing database table using a migration file as shown below

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Results', 'mid_term_type',  Sequelize.ENUM(['first', 'second']));
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.removeColumn('Results', 'mid_term_type'));
  }
};
```

If I migrate the file by running `sequelize db:migrate`, the column is added to the database.

I am having issue is when I run `sequelize db:migrate:undo:all` and then `sequelize db:migrate` to undo the addition of the column.

I get the bellow error:

```
ERROR: type "enum_Results_mid_term_type" already exists
```

How can I remove the "enum_Results_mid_term_type" by running `equelize db:migrate:undo:all`

- sequelize: ^5.22.3
- sequelize-cli: ^5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Results', 'mid_term_type',  Sequelize.ENUM(['first', 'second']));
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('Results', 'mid_term_type'));
      await queryInterface.sequelize.query('drop type enum_Results_mid_term_type;');
  }
};
```

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437924`, We need remove the enum